# remove element from array based on its value?

Tags: php

i've got a regular array with keys and values.

is there a simple way to remove the array element based on its value or do i have to foreach-loop it through and check every value to remove it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://www.php.net/array_filter

PHP 5.3 example to remove "foo" from array $a:

```
<?php
$a = array("foo", "bar");
$a = array_filter($a, function($v) { return $v != "foo"; });
?>
```

The second parameter can be any kind of PHP callback (e.g., name of function as a string). You could also use a function generating function if the search value is not constant.

Comment: Very nice, wasn't familiar with array_fliter

Answer (score 31):

array_diff:

```
$array = array('a','b','c');
$array_to_remove = array('a');

$final_array = array_diff($array,$array_to_remove);
// array('b','c');
```

edit: for more info: http://www.php.net/array_diff

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer`unset($array[array_search('value', $array)]);`**

**Explanation**

1. Find key by its value:  `$key = array_search('value', $array);`
2. remove array element by its key: `unset($array[$key]);`

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that with a combination of `array_search()` and `array_splice()`.

Untested, but should work for **arrays that contain the value only once:**

```
$array = array("Apples", "strawberries", "pears");
$searchpos = array_search("strawberries", $array);
if ($searchpos !== FALSE) {
  array_splice($array, $searchpos, 1);
}
```

Comment: And what does this code do if the array doesn't contain any strawberries?

Comment: and what if strawberries is in the input array twice?

Comment: Most days aren't my day either!

Answer (score 0):

If your array does have unique values, you can flip them with `array_flip`