# Built in PHP function that does this?

Tags: php

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
        if (strlen($value) == 0)
    unset($array[$key]);
```

theres so many built-in array functions so is there one that does this?

Comment: you should define what you mean by "this".

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove element from array based on its value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169669/remove-element-from-array-based-on-its-value)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose you could use **[`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)**, to do that kind of thing *(quoting)* :

> Iterates over each value in the input
> array passing them to the callback
> function. 
> If the  callback  function
> returns `true`, the current value from
> input is returned into the result
> array. 
> Array keys are preserved.

And :

> If no callback is supplied, all
> entries of input equal to `FALSE` *(see
> [converting to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting))* will be
> removed.

For instance, using something like this portion of code :

```
$array = array(
    'test' => 'glop',
    'a' => 123,
    'b' => '',
    'c' => 'blah',
    'd' => '',
);

$array = array_filter($array);
var_dump($array);
```

You'd get the following output :

```
array
  'test' => string 'glop' (length=4)
  'a' => int 123
  'c' => string 'blah' (length=4)
```

I didn't used a callback function, here -- which means that **all "empty" values have been removed** ;; the tricky part being that if I had en entry with `0` as its value, it would have been removed too...

Depending on your situation, that would be acceptable or not... So maybe you'd prefer to use a specific callback function to do exactly what you want, and have a better control over what gets filtered out ?

And here's an example with a callback function :

```
$array = array(
    'test' => 'glop',
    'a' => 0,
    'b' => '',
    'c' => 'blah',
    'd' => '',
);

function my_function($a) {
    if ($a === '') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

$array = array_filter($array, 'my_function');
var_dump($array);
```

**(Note the `'a' => 0` line in the array)**

And we now get :

```
array
  'test' => string 'glop' (length=4)
  'a' => int 0
  'c' => string 'blah' (length=4)
```

i.e. **using a callback function allowed us to specify more clearly what should be filtered out** *(here, lines containing exactly an empty string, without type conversion)*.