# remove entry from array with value = NULL

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove element from array based on its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169669/remove-element-from-array-based-on-its-value)

I have this array

```
$arr = array(
 'key1'=>'value1',
 'key2'=>NULL,
 'key3'=>'value2'
);
```

if I do `implode(',',$arr);` I get: `value1,,value2` (notice the empty space)

Is there a way to skip that NULL values? To get something like this:

`value1,value2`

I could traverse all the array and unset manually the key where the value is NULL, but it's a bit an overkill doens't it?

Edit:

To save time Maybe I could do just one loop to iterate over the array, and in the same loop I check for null values and if isn't null I append it the ','

like this:

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if ($v !== NULL) {
   echo $v.',';
  }
}
```

The problem here is that I have a final ',' at the end.

### Edit

As gordon asked, it ran this test (1000000 iterations)

First using array_filter:

```
$pairsCache = array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>NULL,'key3'=>'value3',
                    'key4'=>'value4','key5'=>'value5');

for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl (";
    $keys='';
    $values='';

    $pairs = array_filter($pairsCache,function($v){return $v !== NULL;});

    $keys = array_keys($pairs);

    //> keys    
    $query .= implode(',',$keys ) . ") VALUES ( '";

    //> values
    $query .= implode("','",$pairs) . "')";
}
```

Time: **7.5949399471283**
Query: "`INSERT INTO tbl (key1,key3,key4,key5) VALUES ( 'value1','value3','value4','value5')`"

Second using only one loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl (";
    $keys='';
    $values='';

    foreach($pairsCache as $k=>$v) {
        if ($v!==NULL) {

            $keys .= $k.',';
            $values .= "'{$v}',";
        }
     }

    $keys=rtrim($keys,',');
    $values=rtrim($values,',');

    $query = $query . $keys . ') VALUES ( ' . $values . ')';

 }
```

Time: **4.1640941333771**
Query: `INSERT INTO tbl (key1,key3,key4,key5,) VALUES ( 'value1','value3','value4','value5')`

Comment: ample results on google as well: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=remove+null+value+array+php - please do research before asking

Comment: I know how to to remove null values, I was just looking for a faster method considering I need to do an implode too

Comment: have you profiled your application and did it say it is too slow with doing implode after array_filter?

Comment: yes it's way faster with only one loop than array_filter + implode. The problem with the loop is that I have to do a mb_substr final to get rid of the final comma

Comment: can you provide a testcase showing numbers please because my tests indicate that a) this is a micro-optimization at best and b) the loop is slower. also, you dont need `mb_substr` but just `trim`

Comment: nice suggestion (I will stick to `rtrim()`) Anyway yes I can provide a testcase, but should I edit my first post to include it?

Comment: yes please. this might make people consider voting to reopen it when it turns out not to be a negligible difference four digits behind the comma.

Comment: well, do you *have* a million iterations? or do you have one iteration? the point im trying to get across is that its pointless optimizing this unless you really have the need. and if you have this many queries, why are you not using prepared statements which will then utilize the query cache?

Comment: fair enough but i dont think this will get reopened then :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$arr = array_filter($arr);
```

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter) removes every value, that evaluates to `false` from `$arr`.

If you need finer control, you can pass a callback as second argument

```
arr = array_filter($arr, function ($item) { return !is_null($item);});
```

At last of course you can iterate over the array yourself

```
foreach (array_keys($arr) $key) {
  if (is_null($arr[$key])) unset($arr[$key]);
}
```

Note, that there is no downside, if you filter and output in two separate steps

Comment: @yes123: Then just pass a callback which explicitly tests the values for `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

`If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.`

```
implode(',', array_filter($arr));
```

Comment: This remove all `FALSE` array values, i.e. also `false` boolean values and `0` and `0.0` numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use bellow code.

**Edited.**

```
function nullFilter($val)
{
    return $val !== NULL;
}
$arr = array( 'key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>NULL, 'key3'=>'value2' );

$filteredArray = array_filter($arr,"nullFilter");

echo implode(',', $filteredArray);
```

Cheers!

Prasad.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do this using only `implode()`.

You can traverse all the array (as you said) maybe in a wrapper `my_implode()` function, or you can use something less elegant such as:

```
trim(preg_replace('/[,]+/', ',', implode(',', $arr)), ',');
```