# Warning message displayed due to array_count_values()

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, keyword

I am using Codeigniter framework of PHP and trying to extract keywords from the page. The complete code for reference can be seen [here](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/04/php_tip_how_extract_keywords_web_page#StripHTMLtagsscriptsandstyles). It is not ready-made though.

The issue is due to the array function in the following line:

```
$keywordCounts = array_count_values( $words );
```

The error message being displayed is as follows:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: array_count_values() [function.array-count-values]: Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!
```

**EDITED:** The array $words for **reference** can be found [here.](http://pastebin.com/bdg3MCfn)

There are no special symbols or invalid characters to my knowledge in the $words array. Hyphens and periods are not read by the function or is there some other issue ?

Comment: Are you passing a *string* into the function or an *array*?!

Comment: Its an array called $words which I am passing as you can see. I have displayed that array as a string of words separated by hyphens for reference. So that someone may find some word which the function cannot read either as a string or an integer.

Comment: can you do a formatted output of your `$words` array as you can see below there is no error when passing your hyphenated list of words exploded into an array to the function.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Edited the link in the question.

Comment: @deceze I've updated the link to display the array.

Comment: Some values in your array seems to be `null` and `null` is neither string nor integer: http://codepad.viper-7.com/0bniV2

Comment: @PLB Yes that was the issue. I converted them into null strings as per solution and the warnings disappeared. Can I remove those null entries from the array ?

Comment: @RahulYadav Yes, you can pretty simply: `$words = array_filter($words, 'is_null');`

Comment: @RahulYadav Forgive me, I eliminated not null values. Here's what you need: http://codepad.viper-7.com/RuQLGw

Comment: @PLB Yes. I was searching some way to do the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you have `null` values in your array. you have to replace them before working with `array_count_values` like this:

```
$x = array('s'=>'ss', 'a',4 , 'sss' => null);

$ar = array_replace($x,array_fill_keys(array_keys($x, null),''));

$v = array_count_values($ar);

var_dump($v);
```

which will result:

```
array (size=4)
  'ss' => int 1
  'a' => int 1
  4 => int 1
  '' => int 1
```

Comment: Okay this works!
Is there any way to remove the null entry from the array ?
And only the first and last entries of array are null. Is this happening due to some other reason or inconsistency ?

Comment: it depends on your code, you haven't posted much code to see why it's behaving like this. and yes, you can delete the null valued indices of your array, take a look [here](http://us3.php.net/array_filter) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169669/remove-element-from-array-based-on-its-value) too.